# Why has [tag:crimea] disappeared?

Tags: discussion

I don't get why [crimea](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crimea) tag has been removed.

If it's some policy like "only nation tags, no regional tags" it makes no sense: nations have a limited span in time and space, so it's completely arbitrary to only allow them as a tag. Please notice that Ukraine itself wasn't an indipendent nation until the dissolution of the USSR.

Plus, it's not like it's a minor region, it has already been the core of some important conflicts.

**edit**: I just noticed I was likely confused with Politics SE, so I'd say we can close this (unless you want to discuss about *creating* such a tag, while you're at it)

Comment: No clue on this one. I'll try and look around.

Comment: Did it used to exist? As near as I can tell, we only have one question appropriate for such a tag that isn't already covered by [tag:crimean-war]

Comment: @T.E.D. oh, that must be a new tag then, I wasn't aware of it

Comment: Re your edit: There is a [crimea tag](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crimea) on Politics.